# Using Gurobipy and solve in Neos Server

Tags: linear-programming, modeling, gurobi, neos

I have a model run in gurobipy (python api) for Gurobi solver and I want to solve it using NEOS Server. How can I send it to NEOS? What is a good way? I want to add a parameter like timelimit so my model could return the best solution so far.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no direct way to do that. Also, Gurobi can reach from Google colab. Do you try that?

Comment: @A.Omidi yes, i have tried that, but sadly the license is limited. It sure can configure the license but i dont know and i think it will be complicated for education license to do so.

Answer (score 2):

There are some possible ways to feed a model into the Neos server:

- First, directly by using an LP, MPS, or some others limited format.
- Second, through connecting with a 3-th party solver like AMPL, GAMS and Pyomo.

You can already upload either GAMS or AMPL file (and also some optional files) into the Neos server, but in the solvers which are being supported by GAMS or AMPL.

Please, be aware that in all of the above the options you can change are limited and it is not possible to access the full specifications.

Comment: Can LP or MPS have parameter configuration like timelimit? If yes, how to include that?

Comment: @overboxed, actually it can do, but I do not try that.

Comment: How to use that? Because the model i want to run will overrun the 8 hours limit of neos server.